# Problem creating time slots in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am going to create time slots of two hours each.

```
start_time=10:00
end_time=24:00
```

Like   `[ [10:00,12:00], [12:00,14:00], [14:00,16:00] ] ...`

I am using that function:

```
function calculate_time_slot(start_time, end_time, interval = "120") {
    var i, formatted_time;
    var time_slots = new Array();
    for (var i = start_time; i <= end_time; i = i + interval) {
        formatted_time = convertHours(i);
        time_slots.push(formatted_time);
    }
    return time_slots;
}
```

but it produce results like this:

```
[
  '10:00', '12:00',
  '14:00', '16:00',
  '18:00', '20:00',
  '22:00', '24:00'
]
```

How to make the pairing like the desired results like:

```
[ [10:00,12:00], [12:00,14:00], [14:00,16:00] ] ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, calculate *two* formatted times: one for the start of the slot, and one for the end of the slot:

```
function calculate_time_slot(startTime, endTime, interval = 120) {
  const timeSlots = [];
  for (let i = startTime; i < endTime; i += interval) {
    const formattedBegin = convertHours(i);
    const formattedEnd = convertHours(i + interval);
    timeSlots.push([formattedBegin, formattedEnd]);
  }
  return timeSlots;
}
```

Make sure to set `interval` to a number, not a string, so that you add instead of concatenate.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there any way to compare two arrays like [2020-03-19, 12:30,14:00] and [2020-03-19, 12:00,14:00] and the result should be true, but as of now it is not a match but contains the similar time

Comment: @CertainPerformance You may need to `return timeSlots;` instead of `return time_slots;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in the `calculate_time_slot` function like so:

```js
let time_slots = ["10:00", "12:00", "14:00", "16:00", "18:00", "20:00", "22:00", "24:00"];

time_slots = time_slots.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => {
  if (i < arr.length - 1) {
    acc.push([`${cur}`, `${arr[i + 1]}`]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(time_slots);
```